# Want to assign the result of the command echo ^`date` to a variable. but when i am trying to do i am not getting the excepted result

Tags: linux, bash

```
echo ^`date`
^Wed Jan 21 05:49:37 CST 2015

deeps=`echo ^`date``
echo $deeps
```

Actual Result:

```
^date
```

Expected Result :

```
^Wed Jan 21 05:49:37 CST 2015
```

Need help on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this method

```
deeps=^$(date)
echo $deeps
```

**Output :**

```
^Wed Jan 21 18:44:25 IST 2015
```

Backticks are horribly outdated and should not be used any more -- using $() instead will save you many headaches

Comment: @Kalanidhi It would be good to note that one of the more pragmatic reasons not to continue using back-ticks is exactly why the OPs original code was failing - they don't nest (at least not very well, or without very careful escaping and what-not). That's one of the reasons they are becoming more obsolete, in light of the fact that you can nest `$( $( $( ... ) ) )`  arbitrarily without inducing escape-rage...

Answer (score 1):

Use a backtick, or use [Command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html). Like

```
# Shell command substitution.
echo ^$(date)
```

or

```
# backticks.
deeps=`date`
echo ^$deeps
```

Both output (the requested)

```
^Wed Jan 21 08:16:01 EST 2015
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply because neither of the other (correct) answers actually explain the problem I'm adding another answer.

tl;dr Compare [the backtick version](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=deeps%3D%60echo+%5E%60date%60%60) to [the `$()` version](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=deeps%3D%24%28echo+%5E%24%28date%29%29)

The difference between

```
echo ^`date`
```

and

```
deeps=`echo ^`date``
```

is how many backticks are on the line and how the shell is parsing the line.

```
echo ^`date`
```

has a single pair of backticks and the shell parses it as (where the `[]` are marking "parts" of the line)

```
[echo] [^][`date`]
```

The

```
`date`
```

bit is then expanded via [Command Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) and so the line becomes

```
[echo] [^Wed Jan 21 05:49:37 CST 2015]
```

and then `echo` spits out the desired `^Wed Jan 21 05:49:37 CST 2015`.

**This** line however

```
deeps=`echo ^`date``
```

is parsed as

```
[deeps][=][`echo ^`][date][``]
```

which you can already see is quite different and not correct (this happens because backticks cannot be nested for the record).

There are now *two* command substitutions on this line `echo ^` and the empty string so the line becomes

```
[deeps][=][^][date][]
```

or with the "words" combined

```
[deeps][=][^date]
```

which then assigns `^date` to `deeps` and `echo $deeps` then gets you `^date`.

The `$()` form of command substitution, no the other hand, *does* nest and thus

```
deeps=$(echo ^$(date))
```

parses as

```
[deeps][=][$([echo] [^][$([date])])]
```

which properly runs both `date` and `echo` on the result. Though, as indicated in the other answers, the wrapping `echo` is not necessary as `deeps=^$(date)` will work just fine by itself.