# Assign a Variable in bash login shell

Tags: bash, unix, escaping, cygwin

i am trying to do this from a Windows command prompt.

```
 C:\cygwin64\bin\bash --login -c "$var="<hallo>" &&
 echo "$var""
```

and i get error :

```
 The system cannot find the file specified.
```

but this works:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash --login  -c 
    "var="hello" && echo "$hello""
```

The **login shell** seems to cause the problem when it gets a '<'. how can i still assign the string with angle brackets to the shell variable?

Comment: Your quotes are off and you have a `$` in variable assignment in the first attempt also. You want `-c "var='<hallo>'"` or similar.

Comment: can you explain why i have to do those mentioned things different than in a normal bash?

Comment: Not using the `$` in an assignment isn't different then normal. Neither is the quoting there. When you say `"var="<hello>" && echo "$hello""` the quotes you intend to be *internal* to the outer string aren't seen that way by the shell. You see `var="<hello>" && echo "$hello"` (i.e. you mentally strip the outer quotes leaving the inner quotes). The shell is dumber than that. It pairs quotes from left to right. So `"var="` is one quoted string, then `<hello>` is unquoted then `" && echo "` is one quoted string then `$hello` is unquoted and then `""` is an empty quoted string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash --login -c "$var="<hallo>" && echo "$var""
```

You are expecting the shell to strip off the *outer* quotes from that argument to `-c` and end up with a string that looks like

```
$var="<hallo>" && echo "$var"
```

but that's not what the shell does.

The shell just matches quotes as it goes along. So the shell sees.

```
["$var="][<hallo>][" && echo "][$var][""].
```

You need to escape the inner quotes from the current shell or use different quotes to avoid this parsing problem.

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash --login -c 'var="<hallo>" && echo "$var"'
```

Note also that I removed the `$` from the start of the variable name in the assignment and that I used single quotes on the outside so that the current shell didn't expand `$var`.

With double quotes on the outside you'd need to use something like this instead.

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash --login -c "var='<hallo>' && echo \"\$var\""
```

For a similar discussion of shell parsing and how things nest (or don't) with backticks you can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28069326/258523).